# Forecasting with own function and forecast package (TLSM)

Tags: r, lapply, forecast

I am foresting with combination of datasets from `fpp2` package and the `tslm()` function from the `forecast` package. In order to get more accurate projection I divide data set into `Training_set` and `Test_set`. Main idea here is to make estimation with linear regression with `Training_set` and apply this model with `Test_set`.

```
   # CODE
      library(fpp2) # required for the data
      library(dplyr)
      library(forecast)
      
      MY_DATA<-uschange[,1:4]
      head(MY_DATA)
      tail(MY_DATA)
      

   # Training set
    Training_set = window(MY_DATA, start=1970, end=c(2010,4))

    # Test set
    Test_set = window(MY_DATA, start=2011, end=c(2016,3))

      # Built own function            
      FORECASTING_FUNCTION_TSLM <- function(Z, hrz = 16) {
        timeseries <- msts(Z, start = 1970, seasonal.periods = 4)
        forecast <- tslm(timeseries~trend+season,biasadj=TRUE)
      }
        
      # Whole set-MY_DATA 
      FORECASTING_LIST_TSLM <- lapply(X = MY_DATA, FORECASTING_FUNCTION_TSLM)
      
      # Training set
      FORECASTING_LIST_TSLM_Training_set<-lapply(Training_set, FORECASTING_FUNCTION_TSLM) 
    
      # Test_set
      FORECASTING_LIST_TSLM_Test_set <- lapply(1:length(FORECASTING_LIST_TSLM_Training_set),function(i) {tslm(Test_set[,i], model = FORECASTING_LIST_TSLM_Training_set[[i]])})#<-----Problem line
```

So far so good. But a problem occurs when I apply this code to `Test_set`. When I try to run last line of this code I got this error message:

```
 Error in formula.default(object, env = baseenv()) : invalid formula
```

So can anybody help me fix this line of code `FORECASTING_LIST_TSLM_Test_set` in order to get an estimation like in the previous examples(`Whole set-MY_DATA`, `Training_set`) and in order to get forecast like previous example (line of code with `Test_set)`?

Comment: `Training_set` is not defined in your code.

Comment: The first parameter of the `tslm` function is `formula`. `Test_set` is not in your code, so we can't see what is in there, but according to the error message it is not a formula. Also, I assume you want to use the model you created with the training set to predict new values using the test set. `tslm` doesn't do prediction, but creates a model.

Comment: I already put Training set and Test set.So please check if you can.